# 'int' object is not iterable on enumerate

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run the following piece of code to extract the topic weights for each topic ie: i

```
for i, row_list in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
    topic_weights.append([w for i, w in row_list[0]])
```

row_list[0] has the following value

```
(1, 0.99338984)
(0, 0.52886134)
(0, 0.10267064)
(1, 0.3627861)
(0, 0.028902475)
(1, 0.9837081)
(0, 0.016032284)
(0, 0.032391597)
(0, 0.60410756)
(0, 0.010807072)
(0, 0.85462123)
(0, 0.010246717)
(0, 0.8862573)
(1, 0.13440639)
(1, 0.9817569)
(0, 0.7687111)
(1, 0.7947949)
```

But I get the error

```
     12 for i, row_list in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
---> 13     topic_weights.append([w for i, w in row_list[0]])
     14 
     15 # Array of topic weights

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Appreciate your help to get this fixed

Comment: `topic_weights.append([w for _, w in row_list])` ?

Comment: yep, there's an extra `[0]` in your list comprehension.